# Is there a way to automatically download all match replays for a specific tournament?

Tags: dota-2

I missed some International 2015 matches over the weekend and I'd like to watch them in the game client. Is there some way that I can automatically download the replays of all matches for that tournament without having to manually download each round of each match?

Aside from making it easier via automation, it would have the added bonus of not "spoiling" the outcome of a match via that popup which occurs after trying to download the 3rd round of a match that didn't go 3 rounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No in game there is nothing. If you find too obnoxious to download all replay manually, you can concider using any of the VOD services (Twitch or Youtube) instead.

Comment: That's unfortunate because I prefer to watch them in the game client so I can move the camera around myself. But thanks for the answer. Maybe they'll add this functionality one day..